# python: theano import error "MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, theano

When importing the theano package:

```
from theano import tensor, scalar
```

I get the following error:

```
To use MKL 2018 with Theano you MUST set "MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU" in your environement.
```

So I looked up the details here:
https://pypkg.com/pypi/theano/f/theano/configdefaults.py

And then tried to isntall the mkl-service on anaconda:

```
conda install -c anaconda mkl-service
```

However, I am getting the same error.

Any ideas? I am on an AWS ubuntu box running python in anaconda jupyter notebook.

Thank you!

Comment: had you found any solutions ?\

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same error. I am using windows. To solve this I added system variable in Windows 10 as follows:

Control Panel -> System & security -> System -> Advanced system setting -> Environment Variable -> add new system variable with variable name = 'MKL_THREADING_LAYER' and variable value = 'GNU' 
and click 'OK'.

I think in ubuntu you should make changes in .bashrc

Answer (score -1):

Try this on the terminal to work it out:

```
cd;echo "export MKL_THREADING_LAYER='GNU'" >> .bashrc;
source .bashrc
```

If you are using Anaconda, restart it.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted.  I'm not a Linux guy, and I know this was a rather brief answer, but nothing about it seems worth a downvote with no explanation...